Use pytesseract OCR to read text from a captcha
I need to use Pytesseract to extract text from this picture:

I'm using this code:
import pytesseract
import cv2
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\guvenlik.jpg"
src = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)

However, my output doesn't match:
My Console Output : 72660wib
How can I read this type of text?

Everything is fine. The captcha works as planned, even though it seems to be very simple.

Not sure if this works for all similar captchas, but this works for this image.
Converts This image:

To: 
and then tries to extract text using additional tesseract options
--oem 1 --psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
from io import BytesIO

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r".\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"    

def enhance_and_resolve(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
    # Uncomment line to see final output of enhancement.
    #cv2.imwrite("Captcha.png",img)
    custom_config = r'--oem 1 --psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = r".\test_img.jpg"
    text = enhance_and_resolve(path)
    print(text)


First of all, thank you, some CAPTCHA works but some does not. I try using while until it matches the correct one, but this time I time out.
